Execution gets stuck when running an API in a loop in Karate 1.4.0 with Java 21
Execution begins normally but gradually slows down, eventually getting stuck at the end.
Could you please suggest any solution for this?

the ONLY solution is if you can replicate this and follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - note that this is an old version of karate and not supported anyway, so use 1.5.0.RC4 or later
